# force query to produce records for each value in lookup table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a lookup table that is 1 to N with a data table. The look up table has the

By example the lookup table contains (Dog, Cat, Bird, Exotic)

The data table has the following fields.
house, animal_type, quantity

If I have data such as

```
house   animal_type   quantity 
  1        dog           1
  1        cat           1
  2        dog           2
  3       exotic         1
```

How do I get a query that will produce the following? (The order of the column headings is immaterial).

```
house   dog   cat  bird  exotic
  1      1     1    0     0
  2      2     0    0     0
  3      0     0    0     1
```

I know about

```
IIF([animals].[quantity] is null,0,[animals].[quantity])
```

But it is not producing a zero record for each animal type even if it is not at that house.

Comment: Can you share the SQL? It sounds like the join to the look up table is an INNER and not an OUTER join.

Comment: @RobPaller I have tried both inner and outer joins and I am still not getting what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can get what you need with a crosstab query.  See the Access help topic: *TRANSFORM Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)*.  And check out the Access *Crosstab Query Wizard* to get started.

It seems you want a column for *bird* even when no house has one.  So add `IN ('dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'exotic')` to the `PIVOT` clause:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(data_table.[quantity]) AS SumOfquantity
SELECT data_table.[house]
FROM data_table
GROUP BY data_table.[house]
PIVOT data_table.[animal_type] IN ('dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'exotic');
```

That query returns Null instead of zero where a `house` does not have a record for an `animal_type`. Include `Nz()` if you prefer zero instead of Null:

```sql
TRANSFORM Nz(Sum(data_table.[quantity]), 0) AS SumOfquantity
```

With that query, Access 2010 gives me this result set from your sample data:

[image]

Comment: this is getting very close to what I need. I tried PIVOT data_table.[animal_type] IN (SELECT * FROM [animal_type]) but it didn't work which leads me to believe that the IN has to be an array. How do I get the array to populate dynamically?

Comment: You can't populate it dynamically.  You could use a VBA procedure to examine the contents of the lookup table and alter the SQL statement text  when needed.

Comment: Due to your guys in put I finally got to where I wanted. I didn't know about the column heading property so I went looking and found the the link below. Basically it is a three query process one being a right join and then a final query that removed the empty row. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa191550(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Without the `IN` piece, the columns will be ordered alphabetically, not in the 'dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'exotic' order your question requested.  If you don't actually care about the column order, please edit the question to clarify that point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRANSFORM` operator in the MS Access to solve your task.

```
TRANSFORM Nz(SUM(quantity), 0)
SELECT house  FROM Test
GROUP BY house
PIVOT animal_type
```

Output of this query

[image]

More information about it you can find here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: that is close to what I am looking for but notice that the heading "bird" is missing. There should be a zero for each house under bird.

Comment: There are no heading with name "bird" because my test data doesn't have it. If you want to have this heading in any case please look at @HansUp solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains step by step to get a crosstab query to show dynamic headings even if there is not associated data for that heading.

[How to Tame the Crosstab Missing Column Beast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa191550(v=office.11).aspx)